# Set a radio box as a required entry with the built-in Magento form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, magento

I have created a few checkboxes that are used on the Magento onepage checkout, I want to use the validation to ensure that the customer selects one of these otherwise the javascript will display the built-in Magento form validation.

```
<div>
 <li class="control horiz-list">
 <input type="radio" class="radio organisation_type validate-one-required" value="1" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('A') ?></li>
 <li class="control horiz-list">
 <input type="radio" class="radio organisation_type validate-one-required" value="2" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('B') ?></li>
 <li class="control horiz-list">
 <input type="radio" class="radio organisation_type validate-one-required" value="3" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('C') ?></li>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
I now have changed the block of code (as above) - the validation works but I submit the error is displayed at the end of the  element rather than the  block so the formatting isn't quite right.

Can anyone suggest how I get the error to be correctly displayed at the end of the  element?

Comment: You can use "required" on your respective radio button, but aren't you already doing that by 'required-entry' in Magneto. So what's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `validate-one-required-by-name` in the class name of the radio button.

or

use `validate-one-required` on the last radio/checkbox in the group

Comment: thanks for that - validation works it is the positioning of the error message div, as it moves the other li's around

Comment: Seems to work... given up on displaying the list items inline as it causes an issue with the error message div positioning